# ZeroMQ socket doesn't receive data when in a goroutine

Tags: sockets, go, zeromq

I am setting up a socket in Go to send and receive data to and from an API which uses ZeroMQ for communication. We need to use goroutines. I understand that ZMQ sockets are extremely not thread safe and to make sure they function properly, all sending and receiving should be done in the same thread.

I can receive all data from all API requests except for one piece of data from one specific API call, a heartbeat that we need to respond to in order to keep the connection alive.

In this API, there are multiple requests that can be made that can result in data being sent back as well as a heartbeat request. Every other API request will send back the data, wait around 5 seconds, then send the heartbeat request needed to keep the connection alive. When the code is run using a single thread, we can receive the heartbeat from every API call. However, when I run that same function through a goroutine, I get back the heartbeat request from every API function EXCEPT for one of them.

Setting up the socket

```golang
import(
    "fmt"
    "os"
    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
)

func testCode() {
    context, err := zmq.NewContext()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("context err: ", err)
        return
    }

    //create Request Socket to talk to Request Server
    fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout,"Attempting to connect to Request Server...")
    sock, err := context.NewSocket(zmq.DEALER)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("socket err: ", err)
        return
    }

    connection.RequestSocket = sock

    err = connection.RequestSocket.Connect(REQUEST_URL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("connect err: ", err)
        return
    }
}


//build the data to be sent up here

    ...

    _, err := socket.SendBytes(bufToSend, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("send err: ", err)
        return
    }

//receive all necessary data from the server
    for mask & info == 0 { 
        reply, err := socket.RecvBytes(0)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err: ", err)
            return
        }
        //process the data
        ...
}
```

So, when I run this main function in a different file, we receive all the correct data and heartbeat requests from every API request

```golang
func main() {
    testCode()
    for {
    }
}
```

However, when I make testCode() a goroutine (as shown below), I fail to receive a heartbeat request for only one of the API calls

```golang
func main() {
    go testCode()
    for {
    }
}
```

What is also interesting is that I monitored all TCP coming in and out of the port we talk to via and have confirmed that the heartbeat requests **are** being sent by the API. So, the heartbeat request is being sent, the data is being recognized by Wireshark as a message coming back from the API but I am not receiving it through the socket for one specific API call. Every other API call sends the heartbeat request and I can see in my program that I received them.

I have made sure that all creation, sending, and receiving for the socket has been done within one thread. I am confused as to why this problem is happening and why it only occurs for only one of the API calls and not all of them.

UPDATE: Apparently for the API call that doesn't receive the heartbeat, I do not receive all the data from the API. I receive about 18910 messages out of the 36872 messages that need to be sent. I don't know why after some time it just stops sending messages when in a goroutine

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. Would you mind to complete the problem definition so as to allow it to become the Community preferred MCVE? The **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of the problem representation. Both the dimension-C and dimension-V are not met. Maybe complete the MCVE using the  prototyped, run-able MCVE to demonstrate your problem representation, as was sketched in https://tio.run/##S8///z8ztyC/qESDSwEIlNJyS5QgrPxiCKMqt1BBKT2zJKM0SS85P1e/IDUpKVUfKGqixKXJpaen9/8/AA and post here a note, once the MCVE is live and running a **V**erifiable mode of the problem above

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve this issue? I am facing a similar issue

Comment: What I found out was that zeromq does not play well with different threads. If you define a socket in one thread and use it in another thread, the results are undefined and weird things can happen (like not receive messages). In the post above, the problem wasnt with the one api, it was with the amount of data that we were receiving. After around 20,000 messages came through on the socket, the socket just stopped receiving messages. After we read and wrote from the socket in one thread, it fixed the problem